# Can MSBuild Alter its own project file?

Tags: msbuild

I have written a custom task that builds files by creating a parallel file with a different extension.

When MSBuild goes and creates such a file I'd like to add it to the project file itself. I'd also like to nest the built file *under* the source (with `DependentUpon`).

Can MSBuild do this? Will it need to reload the project? Can I automate all that?

The following is my .targets file that gets installed by NuGet when my package is added:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="PreCompiler" AssemblyFile="..\tools\Compiler.dll">
</UsingTask>

<UsingTask TaskName="GenerateDependencies" AssemblyFile="..\tools\Compiler.dll">
</UsingTask>

<PropertyGroup>
  <BuildDependsOn>
    $(BuildDependsOn);
    BuildCoffeeFiles;
    BuildLessFiles
  </BuildDependsOn>
  <ContentDir>Content\</ContentDir>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)'=='true'">
  <AvailableItemName Include="CoffeeScript" />
  <AvailableItemName Include="Less" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="GenerateCoffeeDependencies">
  <GenerateDependencies Include="@(CoffeeScript->'%(FullPath)')">
    <Output TaskParameter="Dependencies" ItemName="InputCoffeeFiles"/>
  </GenerateDependencies>
  <ItemGroup>
    <InputCoffeeFiles
        Include="@(InputCoffeeFiles->Distinct())"
        KeepDuplicates='false' />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>

<Target Name="BuildCoffeeFiles"
        DependsOnTargets="GenerateCoffeeDependencies"
        Inputs="@(InputCoffeeFiles)"
        Outputs="@(CoffeeScript->'%(RelativeDir)%(Filename).js')">
  <PreCompiler Include="@(CoffeeScript->'%(FullPath)')" />
</Target>

<Target Name="GenerateLessDependencies">
  <GenerateDependencies Include="@(Less->'%(FullPath)')">
    <Output TaskParameter="Dependencies" ItemName="InputLessFiles"/>
  </GenerateDependencies>
  <ItemGroup>
    <InputLessFiles
        Include="@(InputLessFiles->Distinct())"
        KeepDuplicates='false' />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>

<Target Name="BuildLessFiles"
        DependsOnTargets="GenerateLessDependencies"
        Inputs="@(InputLessFiles)"
        Outputs="@(Less->'%(RelativeDir)%(Filename).css')">
  <PreCompiler Include="@(Less->'%(FullPath)')" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Could you provide some code from the msbuild? The order in this case is important.

Comment: That's almost the full content.  The Compiler.dll handles live-recompilation when needed in my Nancy App since I don't particularly like Squishit or Cassette

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modify .csproj in MSBuild](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25435857/modify-csproj-in-msbuild)

Comment: @Tom I had forgotten I wrote that post.  Deleted it. This post is much better asked anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a XslTransformation msbuild task in your project, before you build it, adding the required file.

This is the sample transformation file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ms="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Identity. -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//ms:Compile[@Include='Program.cs']">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
      <xsl:element name="DependentUpon"
         namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
           <xsl:text>Output.cs</xsl:text>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here is the msbuild target sample file:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">

    <Target Name="Build">
        <XslTransformation
           XmlInputPaths="ConsoleApplication1.csproj"
           OutputPaths="ConsoleApplication1.transformed.csproj"
           XslInputPath="proj.xslt">
        </XslTransformation>

        <MSBuild Projects="ConsoleApplication1.transformed.csproj" Targets="Build" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

**You will need to build with .NET 4.0 at least. For this specify the ToolsVersion in msbuild file.**